# Asp.Net core Deleting an entry from table in database: what is the outcome

Tags: database, asp.net-core, sql-delete

I have a database with table Photos and table Categories. Each photo is related to one category by categoryId field.
What happens when I delete one category from Categories table? Will the photos with that category be updated with a null value in the categoryID? Or how will entity-framework react to this change?

Another question can I then reset with a mass-change the values of those categories in the photos table? And how can I do that?

Comment: instead of asking why don't you run the code and see what happens?

Comment: @Saurabh thanks for replying

Answer (score 1):

hi if you have created relationship between table(using foreign key) then only the deletion of parent table will affect deletion of child table. if you just created table separately and managing relationship with your code then it will not affect the child table. if you are creating using model first approach in entity framework with specifying relation then relationship will be automatically created in backend.

their are four options available in sql on deletion of parent entity

1)No Action 
2)Cascade 
3)SET NULL 
4)SET Default

to know how it will affect check this article 
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2365/sql-server-foreign-key-update-and-delete-rules/

Answer (score 1):

That would depend completely on how the ORM that is used defines the database model.

Assuming you use **Entity Framework** then you can define exactly how EF should react to that situation. In the *DbContext* you should find a *OnModelCreating* method in wich you can specify per table what restrictions you want on the table. There you can also define the behaviour of the *OnDelete* of a foreign key.

If you are not using EF but have your own or a **different ORM** then again, it depends on how that ORM is configured.

Simple check **if you dont know about the used ORM** is this: Does the field *in the database* have a foreign key and how is that configured? Also, is the field categoryID (as defined in the database) nullable? if so, then it apparently doesnt need the relation and shouldnt result in related deletes.